# Using Synchronized with Thread-Safe Collection?

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have the following code:

```
    private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Book> shelf;

    public Library(ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Book> shelf){         
        this.shelf = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Book>(shelf);       
    }
```

Given that I'm using a thread safe collection would the following method be okay to use or do I need to worry about thread safety?

```
    public void addBook(int index, Book add){
        shelf.put(index, add);
    }
```

If the above method isn't safe to use, would adding synchronized be the proper way of doing it? Like so,

```
public synchronized void addBook(int index, Book add){
    shelf.put(index, add);
}
```

Comment: you don't need to worry about thread safety with them  AFAIK

Comment: @Leo, You need to worry about thread safety any time there is data shared between threads.  Using a thread-safe class means that you don't have to worry about the internal consistency of any _single_ instance of that class, but if your code depends on consistency _between_ two or more objects, then _your code_ will need to implement some kind of synchronization to guarantee that consistency.  The fact that each of the individual objects is _internally_ consistent won't be enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `synchronized` keyword essentially puts a mutex lock around the entire `addBook` method.

A `ConcurrentHashMap` ensures that all operations (such as put) are threadsafe, but using retrieval operations (such as get) in conjunction might cause you to come across a situation where you are retrieving contents from the Hashmap at the same time that you are putting, and get unexpected results.

Individually, all methods in the `ConcurrentHashMap` are thread-safe, but used in conjunction in separate threads you cannot necessarily be certain of the order in which they execute. (Thanks to @jtahlborn for clarification).

So, in your specific case, adding the `synchronized` keyword to the `addBook` method is redundant.

If you're doing more complex operations involving multiple retrievals and puts, you may want to consider some extraneous locking (your own mutex).

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: If I wanted to add a method that would retrieve a specific book then I would have to use the synchronized keyword with the method correct?

Comment: @AnnabelleRosemond it may or may not be necessary. It depends on how accurate your data needs to be on each retrieval. For example, if you do 3 `put`s and 1 `get`, depending on which thread is calling the `get` you may see 0-3 results. In order to ensure everything is synchronized, you need to lock the `put` and the `get` methods using the same lock, but this may cause you to lose the potential performance gains from using threads. It's a trade-off of accuracy and performance.

Comment: If the get operation happens-after the put, the object as well as all other memory changes that happened-before will be visible.

Comment: @Bax That depends; if thread 1, 2, and 3 are the threads executing the `put`s, but the Main thread is calling the `get`, the Main thread may have fully executed the `get` method before the other three threads even got a slice of CPU time to execute their `put`. If, however, these 4 operations all happen on the same thread, then you're correct.

Comment: This answer is not accurate.  the get() method of ConcurrentHashMap are _certainly_ thread safe!

Comment: @jtahlborn You're right, I re-read my answer and realized it contained confusing language. I've edited it. What I meant was that using write and read operations in conjunction can not be assumed thread-safe.

Comment: First, those are still "thread safe".  you may not be able to determine which will happen first, but that's not specific to ConcurrentHashMap.  that's true for any use of concurrency.

Comment: @jtahlborn Yes, individually they are thread-safe. I think we're agreeing with each other but using different language. I simply mean exactly what you're saying, you can't determine the state of the object in terms of which operations will execute first. I'll edit my answer to be even more clear.

Comment: @Hypino it does not depend, the statement is correct as I stated it. Concurrent operations still happen one before another, so if the get occurs before put, visibility is guaranteed.

Comment: @Bax I think we're talking about two separate situations. The situation I am talking about involves multiple threads. If a `put` is in one thread and the `get` is in another thread, you cannot guarantee which one executes first. Even if I call `put` in thread1 before `get` in thread2.

Comment: @Hypino I only stated about when things happen (actually). If thread X executes the get before thread Y executes the put, visibility is guaranteed.

Comment: @Bax Oh absolutely, no arguments there. If there is some part of my answer that seems to contradict that, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry if you are ONLY calling `shelf.put`. Since `put` is already threadsafe then you are ok.

You would need to worry about synchronized when you are doing multiple operations that *together* need to be atomic. For example, maybe you had a method called `updateBook` that looks like

```
public void updateBook(int index, String newTitle){
    Book book = shelf.get(index);
    // do something with book or maybe update book.setTitle(newTitle);
    shelf.put(index, book);
}
```

This method would have to be `synchronized` because otherwise anther thread can get a book that is not updated yet.

Comment: you don't typically want to use synchronized with concurrent data structures.  ideally, you should use the "extra" atomic methods those structures provide to avoid global locks (which is the ponit of the data structure in the first place).

Comment: Yes, not typically. Typically being the keyword. Just trying to make a point about doing atomic operations here though. I have seen deadlocks when synchronized and blocking queues have been used together. I think that might be too much for this answer though.