# Thread-safe Set that is updated using a timestamp?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Set that holds thousands of phone numbers. When my service receives a new account request, it checks the phone number against the list to make sure it isn't a known spam number. If the phone number list is older than a week, the method fetches the latest copy of the list from an external server and reads it into memory. It then updates the "timestamp" variable to reflect the last updated time of the list. Something like:

```
public class SpamPhoneNumberManager() {

  private Set<String> spamPhoneNumbers;
  private long timestamp;

  public SpamPhoneNumberManager() {
    updateSpamPhoneNumbers();
  }

  public Set<String> getSpamPhoneNumbers() {
    if(timestamp - System.currentTimeMillis() > ONE_WEEK) {
      updateSpamPhoneNumbers();
    }
    return spamPhoneNumbers;
  }

  private void updateSpamPhoneNumbers() {
    Set<String> newSpamPhoneNumbers = new HashSet<>();
    //populate set from file on server
    spamPhoneNumbers = Collections.unmodifiableSet(newSpamPhoneNumbers);
    timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

}
```

Multiple threads can call the get() method concurrently. In this current implementation, I can't think of any concurrency problems. In the worst case I could come up with, the list is updated consecutively by multiple threads. Is there a need to make this threadsafe? If so, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: `updateSpamPhoneNumbers` can be call n times while is updating. You should use a lock.. and why do you use static variables? and also you could return an old view of your list

Comment: Your code is not quite right, variables are `static` in context, but not the methods

Comment: I see this kind of code a lot, whoever is unlucky enough to trigger the "update" will have to wait for it to complete, causing a lot of latency to that call.  If latency is not an issue then this is fine, if it is, consider using a self populating cache that does refreshes in the background.

Comment: yeah sorry, I just wrote this in a text editor a couple minutes ago. updated variables to not be static. @nachokk, do I need to lock the logic in the get() function? How could it return an old list? the timestamp isn't updated until the updated list is written to memory, a thread would never see an updated timestamp without an updated set, right?

Comment: @BartW A simple fix would be to set `getSpamPhoneNumbers()` `synchronized`. This guarantees that only one thread can access the `updatePhoneNumbers()`-method of an object at one point in time.

Comment: Thanks, @Turing85. With that change, the only problem will be the latency john16384 mentions, right? In this case, latency isn't too much of an issue, so that sounds like a good fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a need to make this threadsafe?

Your current class is NOT threadsafe because multiple threads can call `getSpamPhoneNumbers()` and checks the `if` condition, which is not atomic.
So, multiple threads try to call `updateSpamPhoneNumbers` causing the race condition, so there will be intermediate states where in `spamPhoneNumbers` gets one value & `timestamp` with a different value (if any other thread calls `get` method finds and returns these inconsistent values explained below).

In short, there will be a scenario that can happen like below:

Thread1 -> updates `spamPhoneNumbers` with `spamPhoneNumbersThread1` and sets `timestampThread1`

Thread2 -> updates `spamPhoneNumbersThread2` (assume still `timestamp` is NOT updated)

Thread3 -> calls `getSpamPhoneNumbers()` and doesn't enter the if block and returns `spamPhoneNumbersThread2` (validated against `timestampThread1`)

The important point here is that there is clearly a race condition and you will see inconsistent (from different threads) `timestamp` and `spamPhoneNumbers` values.

> If so, what's the best way to do this?

The solution is you need synchronization on `spamPhoneNumbers` object so that once thread only can access it at a time.

```
public Set<String> getSpamPhoneNumbers() {
    synchronized(spamPhoneNumbers) {
      if(timestamp - System.currentTimeMillis() > ONE_WEEK) {
        updateSpamPhoneNumbers();
      }
    }
    return spamPhoneNumbers;
  }

  private void updateSpamPhoneNumbers() {
    Set<String> newSpamPhoneNumbers = new HashSet<>();
      //populate set from file on server
      spamPhoneNumbers = Collections.unmodifiableSet(newSpamPhoneNumbers);
      timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }
```

**P.S.:** You don't need any synchronization inside `updateSpamPhoneNumbers()` as it is `private`, but if you change your mind in future and this method becomes `public`, you must need synchronization here as well.

Comment: Minor point: it is sufficient to set only `getSpamPhoneNumbers()` `synchronized`. One could set `updateSpamNumbers()` `synchronized` as well, but this is (with the given code) optional.

Comment: thanks, agreed, just updated and specified that why it is not needed

Comment: And you could the method `synchronized` instead of a block. Locking would then occur on `this` instead of `spamPhoneNumbers`, but - like with `updateSpamPhoneNumbers` - it should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to only add some items to your phone numbers collection, declaring  your collection with any thread-safe collection type, e.g. [Synchronized Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), will be enough.

Read more here : [Using Synchronized with Thread-Safe Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230014/using-synchronized-with-thread-safe-collection)

Answer (score 0):

I would change your implementation. Using a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) as a background thread with a fixed rate for a week to update the catalog or using a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Here is an example using Timer.

```
public class SpamPhoneNumberManager {

    private Set<String> spamPhoneNumbers;
    private final Timer timer;
    private volatile boolean isUpdating = false;


    public SpamPhoneNumberManager() {
        this.timer = new Timer("updater", true);
        this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SpamPhoneNumberManager.this.updateSpamPhoneNumbers();
            }
        }, 0, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);// one week // week

    }

    public Set<String> getSpamPhoneNumbers() {
        if(isUpdating){
            // here is your decision what to do, or wait blocking until is updated, or return an old copy, or exception to retry later 
        }
        return this.spamPhoneNumbers;
    }

    private void updateSpamPhoneNumbers() {
        this.isUpdating = true;
        Set<String> newSpamPhoneNumbers = new HashSet<>();
        // populate set from file on server
        this.spamPhoneNumbers = Collections.unmodifiableSet(newSpamPhoneNumbers);
        this.isUpdating = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I originally was using the executor framework to do the same (didn't know about Timer, though!), but I switched to the current approach. What are some advantages of this implementation over the current?

Comment: 1) You are updating in the same calling thread, when it has to update then you block that thread , that is not good 2) you are asking each time in the get method if should be updated, this way is easier... if you are using a IOC container as Spring you have @Scheduled annotation to do the same thing with annotation style

Comment: 3) is much simpler than the other answer.. you decouple responsabilities with thread, one thread to update, the other to attend requests

Comment: Yes you can use ScheduledExecutorService also, you have more control there, but as is just a simple background thread ypu can use Timer that is oldie